# Make the programme wait until I speak

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

i am coding a virtual assistant, everything is fine it listens to my audio input and responses correctly, but it continiously keeps listening to me, I can't figure out how to make it listen only when I speak.

TL;DR- I want a code which makes my programme wait until a certain conditon is met (here, that condition is me speaking)

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts
import subprocess
import datetime
import webbrowser
import time


now = datetime.datetime.now()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

speaker = tts.init()

x = speaker.getProperty('voices')
speaker.setProperty('voice', x[1].id)

y = speaker.getProperty('rate')
speaker.setProperty('rate' , 175)



def record_audio(ask = False):
    
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
        if ask:
            tts.speak(ask)
        print("listening")
        
        voice_data = ''
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic , 0.05)
        audio = speech_recognition.Recognizer().listen(mic)
        
        try:
            
            voice_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio , language = "en-IN")
        
            
            
        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            tts.speak('Sorry, I did not understand what you just said. Please try again.')

        except speech_recognition.RequestError:
            tts.speak("Sorry, my speech service is down for the time being. Please try again later.")
        
        return voice_data


def responses(command):

    if 'hello' in command:
        tts.speak("hello sir, how can I help you.")
        

    elif  'what is your name'  in command:
        tts.speak("My name is Otto Octavius") 

    elif  'time' in command:
        tts.speak(now.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))

    elif 'date' in command:
        tts.speak(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    elif 'open' and 'telegram' in command:
        tts.speak("opening telegram")
        subprocess.Popen("D:\My Folder\My Softwares\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe")

    elif 'close' and 'telegram' and 'window' in command:
        tts.speak("closing telegram")
        subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Telegram.exe"])
    
    elif 'open' and 'binance' in command:
        tts.speak("opening binance")
        subprocess.Popen("D:\My Folder\My Softwares\Binance\Binance.exe")

    elif 'close' and 'binance' in command:
        tts.speak('closing binance')
        subprocess.call(["taskkill" , "/F" , "IM" , 'Binance.exe'])

   

    elif 'my folder' in command:
        tts.speak('opening my folder')
        webbrowser.open("D:\My Folder")

    elif 'search' in command:

        search_object = record_audio("What do you want me to search for?")
        url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search_object)
        tts.speak('Searching for ' + search_object)
        webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open_new_tab(url)

    elif 'bye' in command:
        tts.speak('Good bye sir, have a nice day ahead')
        exit()
    
    elif'good bye' in command:
        tts.speak('Good bye sir, have a nice day ahead.')
        exit()
    
    elif 'good night' in command:
        tts.speak("Good Night)
        exit()
    
    
        


time.sleep(1)
tts.speak("Welcome, how can I help you")
while 1:
    command = record_audio()
    responses(command)
```

Comment: how will it know that you are speaking without continuously (or at least in frequent intervals) listening?

Comment: Really, really thank you, I know it might seem weird but this question of yours literally solved my problem.